# Как подключить несколько js скриптов к разным страницам

Tags: javascript, php, html

Есть just скрипты, которые используются на нескольких страницах. Я вручную проставляю версии им, чтобы они обновлялись у пользователей. Могу ли я сделать, чтобы я менял версии только в одном месте, а они менялись автоматически у всех? Или есть какой то вариант получше?

Comment: Страницы генерируются с помощью php? Тогда просто пишите версии в одном-единственном месте и на каждой странице с помощью php просто читайте это одно-единственное место и печатайте версию

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так понял вы прописываете версию для того, чтобы браузер клиента скачивал новый js файл, а не использовал старый из кэша.
Есть простое решение, которое автоматически работает как только вы изменяете файл (работает для любых статических файлов):

```
<script src="/js/file.js?t=<?= filemtime('/js/file.js'); ?>"></script>
```

Как только вы перезапишите условный "file.js" на сервере, все браузеры посетителей скачают новую версию.